# Making sense of error message related to type inference when using a method reference

Tags: java, java-stream

I wanted to create a list of non-alphabetic characters from a string, so I wrote:

```java
str.chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
        .filter(Predicate.not(Character::isAlphabetic))
        .toList();
```

However this throws the following error message:

> no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Character conforms to
> Integer inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality
> constraints: Integer lower bounds: Character

I didn't fully understand the error message, but I figured that it is caused by `Character#isAlphabetic` taking in `int codePoint` as a parameter instead of a char because replacing `Character::isAlphabetic` with `Character::isUpperCase` (for example) which takes in a `char` works fine.

Now, if I write:

```java
str.chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
        .filter(c -> !Character.isAlphabetic(c))
        .toList();
```

it compiles just fine, and I'm not even that surprised/confused. However, if I write

```java
str.chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
        .filter(Predicate.not(c -> Character.isAlphabetic(c)))
        .toList();
```

it also compiles just fine, which definitely confuses me because isn't `Character::isAlphabetic` basically equivalent to `c -> Character.isAlphabetic(c)`? Well, apparently it isn't in all cases (because AFAIK it is in most)

So my 2 questions are:

1. What exactly is this error message saying? I do understand it to an extent but definitely not completely
2. Why does the first version not work but the third does?

Comment: You're asking the compiler to accept `isAlphabetic(Charater)` where it takes `isAlphabetic(int)`: that's two implicit conversions that you expect: `Character` to `char`, then `char` to `int`. It doesn't do that.

Comment: How does it work fine with a lambda (3rd example) tho? is it something specific to method references where if it has to do more than one conversion it won't work?

Comment: I see what you're saying. Seems like type inference doesn't see `Predicate.not(c -> Character.isAlphabetic(c))` and `Predicate.not(Character::isAlphabetic)` as equivalent.

Comment: You can get it to work with `Predicate.<Character>not(Character::isAlphabetic)`, but there's an answer to be found on the difference.

Comment: yeah that's exactly what im trying to understand, somehow they're not equivalent in this case.

and dang, i did try `Predicate<Character>.not(Character::isAlphabetic)` i forgot that the dot has to be before the generic type.

Comment: As a side note, it makes more sense to use `str.chars() .filter(c -> !Character.isAlphabetic(c)) .mapToObj(c -> (char)c)`, so instead of boxing `int` to `Character`, just to unbox them to `int` again for the predicate, only box elements that passed the filter and will get collected to the `List`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between `Character::isAlphabetic` and `c -> Character.isAlphabetic(c)` is that since `Character.isAlphabetic(int)` is not an overloaded method, the former is an [exact method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1-400) whereas the latter is an [implicitly typed lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.1-210).

We can show that an inexact method reference is accepted the same way as an implicitly typed lambda expression:

```java
class SO71643702 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "123abc456def";
        List<Character> l = str.chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
            .filter(Predicate.not(SO71643702::isAlphabetic))
            .toList();
        System.out.println(l);
    }

    public static boolean isAlphabetic(int codePoint) {
        return Character.isAlphabetic(codePoint);
    }

    public static boolean isAlphabetic(Thread t) {
      throw new AssertionError("compiler should never choose this method");
    }
}
```

This is accepted by the compiler.

However, this doesn’t imply that this behavior is correct. Exact method references may help in overload selection where inexact do not, as specified by [§15.12.2.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2):

> Certain argument expressions that contain implicitly typed lambda expressions ([§15.27.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.1)) or inexact method references ([§15.13.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1)) are ignored by the applicability tests, because their meaning cannot be determined until the invocation's target type is selected.

In contrast, when it comes to the [15.13.2. Type of a Method Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2), there is no difference between exact and inexact method references mentioned. Only the target type determines the actual type of the method reference (assuming that the target type is a functional interface and the method reference is congruent).

Consequently, the following works without problems:

```java
class SO71643702 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "123abc456def";
        List<Character> l = str.chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
            .filter(Character::isAlphabetic)
            .toList();
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

<sup>Of course, that’s not the original program logic</sup>

Here, `Character::isAlphabetic` still is an exact method reference, but it’s congruent with the target type `Predicate<Character>`, so it works not different to

```java
Predicate<Character> p = Character::isAlphabetic;
```

or

```java
Predicate<Character> p = (Character c) -> Character.isAlphabetic(c);
```

It’s not as if the insertion of a generic method into nesting of method invocations will stop the type inference from working in general. As discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53516501/2711488) to a similar fragile type inference issue, we can insert a generic method not contributing to the resulting type without problems:

```java
class SO71643702 {
    static <X> X dummy(X x) { return x; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "123abc456def";
        List<Character> l = str.chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
            .filter(dummy(Character::isAlphabetic))
            .toList();
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

and even “fix” the problem of the original code by inserting the method

```java
class SO71643702 {
    static <X> X dummy(X x) { return x; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "123abc456def";
        List<Character> l = str.chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
            .filter(Predicate.not(dummy(Character::isAlphabetic)))
            .toList();
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

It’s important that there is no subtype relationship between `Predicate<Character>` and `Predicate<Integer>`, so the `dummy` method can not translate between them. It’s just returning exactly the same type as the compiler inferred for its argument.

I consider the compiler error a bug, but as I said at the other answer, even if the specification backs up this behavior, it should get corrected, in my opinion.

---

As a side note, for this specific example, I’d use

```java
var l = str.chars()
    .filter(c -> !Character.isAlphabetic(c))
    .mapToObj(c -> (char)c)
    .toList();
```

anyway, as this way, you’re not boxing `int` values to `Character` objects, just to unbox them to `int` again in the predicate, but rather, only box values after passing the filter.

Answer (score 0):

**Using an example from the book OCP Java 8 :**

```
1: List<? super IOException> exceptions = new ArrayList<Exception>();
2: exceptions.add(new Exception()); // DOES NOT COMPILE
```

**Explanation of writers** :
Line 1 reference a List that could be List or List or
List. Line 2 does not compile because we could have a List and
an Exception object wouldn’t fit in there.

**The same example given by you :**

```
"hello".chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> (char) c) // generate a  Stream<Character>
        .filter(Predicate.not(Character::isAlphabetic))
 // filter signature :  Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate);
```

So we have a : `Predicate<? super Character>` , using the method reference  `Predicate.not(Character::isAlphabetic)`  will do the conversion from Character to int and next int will be autoboxed to Integer , **so we will have an Integer instance**, but our lower bound cannot accept an Integer Objects , it can accept a Character instances (it allow super references as Integer ,Object but not a Super Instances ). You are trying here to passe an instance from a super type to a lower bound generics and this will confuse the compiler.

Using this code : `c -> Character.isAlphabetic(c)` , you are declaring that you accept the Character (Character instance and Character reference) and passing it to the method.

Answer (score -1):

Java will *either* autobox/autounbox *or* perform a safe primitive-to-primitive cast.

This

```
filter(Predicate.not(c -> Character.isAlphabetic(c)
```

offers *2* opportunities for these automatic operations:

- one for the filter Object to the lambda parameter, and
- one for the lambda parameter to the `isAlphabetic()` parameter

which allows this to compile.

The first operation is to unbox `Character` to `char` to make the lambda parameter a `char`. The second operation (safely) casts `char` to `int`.

Comment: @Bohemian♦ , is that a rule : "The method reference only provides 1 opportunity" ?

Comment: Why has a method reference less conversion opportunities than a lambda expression? As stated in the question’s comments, `Predicate.<Character>not(Character::isAlphabetic)` does work. Without having more “conversion opportunities”.

Comment: …to debunk the explanation completely, `.filter(Character::isAlphabetic)` works without problems, doing the conversion from `Character` to `int` in one step.

Comment: @holger `filter(Predicate.not(Character::isAlphabetic))` explodes for me just like OP says it does. See [live demo](https://www.ideone.com/1aEetL).

Comment: I didn’t say otherwise. I said, `Predicate.<Character>not(Character::isAlphabetic)` does work and so does `.filter(Character::isAlphabetic)`. Your answer doesn’t explain why these two cases work but the OP’s doesn’t.

Comment: Actually i am curious as to why `Predicate.<Character>not(Character::isAlphabetic)` works as well

Comment: I Think there is a relation with the lower bound of filter method signature :  Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate);